# How to automate mouse movement and keyboard strokes?

Tags: scripting, automation, hotkeys, recorder

I need to copy and paste some stuff. I was thinking the easiest way was to record my mouse movement (and maybe keyboard) and then just repeating that. Is this the most efficent solution for me? I have no automated software experience whatsoever.

I was thinking about using this : http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/59817-mouse-movement-click-recorder/, but it doesn't record the keyboard. This task is time-sensitive, so that's why I need it to be beginner friendly (because I have no experience).

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling found out few tools:
[Mouse Recorder Pro](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/Mouse-Recorder-Pro-2.shtml)
[Mini Mouse Macro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/minimousemacro/)

Both look like what you need. I'm sure you're able to find more tools.